# atoi not giving correct output

Tags: c++

Can somebody tell me why the value of variable 'b' is 25, I was expecting a value of 2. This is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    stringstream ss;
    string sss;
    unsigned short rt=52;
    ss<<rt;
    sss=ss.str();

    cout<<sss.at(0)<<"     "<<sss.at(1)<<endl;
    char ch1=sss.at(0);
    char ch2=sss.at(1);
    //int ui=atoi((char*)sss.at(0))*10+atoi((char*)sss.at(1)); //can somebody tell me what's wrong in this statement(causes segmentation fault)
    cout<<ch1<<"     "<<ch2<<endl;
    int a=atoi(&ch1);
    int b=atoi(&ch2); //giving output as 25
    cout<<a<<"    "<<b<<endl;
    int c=a*10+b;
    int ui=atoi(&ch1)*10+atoi(&ch2);

    cout<<ui<<"     "<<c<<endl;
}
```

Please note my compiler doesn't support C++11 standard.

Comment: `atoi` requires a pointer to a zero-terminated string of characters. Passing it anything else is undefined.

Comment: You can convert a text digit to a numeric digit by subtracting `'0'`.  No need to call a function.

Comment: Thomas has a better approach for this particular case, but make a note for the future: Never use `atoi()`.  The standard function `strtol()` does all the same things, better.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Not to mention `stoi` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`atoi()` as stated in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) expect a null-terminated string and tries to convert whole string to the number so trying to use it for individual digits is simply wrong, just apply it to the whole string:

```
int ui = std::atoi( sss.c_str() );
```

Answer (score 2):

atoi should take a zero-terminated C string as input argument
and you pass just pointer to the character. This is undefined behavior and there can be any result (in some cases program can crash)

But why you actually get 25?

Probably both variables ch1 and ch2 are stored sequentially in memory and there is some non-digit character after them. atoi() treats pointer to ch1 as zero-terminated c-string and reads data from memory until it finds the first non-digit character, and then converts result to integer. That's why you get 25. But actually it is undefined behavior you may get another result or program crash with another compiler (or even another compilation params).

I can also see one more question in the line of code that is commented out

```
//int ui=atoi((char*)sss.at(0))*10+atoi((char*)sss.at(1)); //can somebody tell me what's wrong in this statement(causes segmentation fault)
```

There is segmentation fault because you convert the value of char ('2' or '5') to pointer "char*". So ASCII code of these character treated as memory address. Of course this address is incorrect and access to the memory causes segmentation fault.

Comment: 'following characters in your memory "25\0"' how do you know that?

Comment: actually  this is undefined behavior to pass C++ string. And there can be any result, in some cases program can crash. But author of the question was curious how he could get 25 as the result. C++ string (sss) stores data as char array with '\0' (it is not standard, but all compilers do it like this)

Comment: `std::string` may store data whatever way but OP does not pass pointer to `std::string` content, so you cannot know what resides in memory after ch1 and ch2

Comment: @Sandro Also [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) is required to return a null-terminated string.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but he just copies the char returned by method at()

Comment: @Sandro Nevermind, didn't see the commented out part first.